# Why array indexing isn't working inside an object in a mongoDB collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to implement a slot booking system in mongoDB.
I want to push a string, which is a userId (ObjectId from users collection) into an array called **userId** which is in one of the many similar objects, present in  the **slotsAvailable** array.

The issue is, I am not able to target a particular slot from slotsAvailable array. I tried indexing as well because slotsAvailable is an array.

I want to select a particular day (say, day:1) and from 'slotsAvailable' object I want to select a particular slot through it's Id (say, id:5). After that, I want to push an ObjectId into **userId** array, increment the **count** till 9 and when the count reaches 9, I want to update **isAvailable** to *false*.

What query shall I run to achieve the same?

I executed the following query :

```
db.vaccines.findOne({day:1})
```

It returned:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("60c8b8cf7bd10f9d7876f3b1"),
"totalBooking" : 0,
"day" : 1,
"slotsAvailable" : [
    {
        "userId" : [ ],
        "count" : 0,
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "id" : 0
    },
    {
        "userId" : [ ],
        "count" : 0,
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "id" : 1
    },
    {
        "userId" : [ ],
        "count" : 0,
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "id" : 2
    },
    {
        "userId" : [ ],
        "count" : 0,
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "id" : 3
    },
    {
        "userId" : [ ],
        "count" : 0,
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "id" : 4
    },
    {
        "userId" : [ ],
        "count" : 0,
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "id" : 5
    },
    {
        "userId" : [ ],
        "count" : 0,
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "id" : 6
    },
    {
        "userId" : [ ],
        "count" : 0,
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "id" : 7
    },
    {
        "userId" : [ ],
        "count" : 0,
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "id" : 8
    },
    {
        "userId" : [ ],
        "count" : 0,
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "id" : 9
    },
    {
        "userId" : [ ],
        "count" : 0,
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "id" : 10
    },
    {
        "userId" : [ ],
        "count" : 0,
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "id" : 11
    },
    {
        "userId" : [ ],
        "count" : 0,
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "id" : 12
    },
    {
        "userId" : [ ],
        "count" : 0,
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "id" : 13
    }
]
```

}

My nodeJs code is:

```js
async function bookVaccineSlot(args){
    const {userId} = args
    
    // get vaccine collection from DB
    const vaccines = mongoose.connection.collection('vaccines');

    // call getSlotId routine to get the value of slot number using slotTime( slot start time in 24-hour format)
    const {day,slotTime} = args;

    const slotID = getSlotId(slotTime);

    if(1<=slotID && slotID<=14){

        let index = slotID - 1;
        let query = {day:day,"slotsAvailable.id":index};

        let updatedDocument = {
            $push:{
                "slotsAvailable.$.userId":userId,
            },
            $set: {
                "slotsAvailable.$.": 'slotsAvailable.count'+1
            }
        }
        // get slot of particular day from the 'vaccines' collection, fetched above
        const vaccinationDay = await vaccines.updateOne(query,updatedDocument)
        return vaccinationDay;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://carbon.now.sh/ohAaWBfUXX1drCSX8TGe

Comment: The above link is the detailed snippet of what's happening after entering the same query in mongo shell and MongoDB driver in NodeJS

Answer (score 0):

You can use MongoDB queries. What you need is and `$and` operation for combining `day:1` and a `$in` to search inside an array.
So, you can run `db.vaccines.findOne{$and : [{day:1} , {'slotsAvailable.userId': {$in :[5]} } ]}` in mongoose to find all documents where day is 1 and userId is 5.
Do check the datatypes.

MongoDB queries : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/
Mongoose queries : https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html